# Why does a pipe in write mode outputs something?

Tags: c++, pipe

While I was playing with pipes in c++ I stumbled accross something rather interesting.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    FILE *pystream = popen("python","w"); // Calling the python console

    fprintf(pystream,"print(2+3)"); // Making it do something   

    pclose(pystream); // Closing the pipe

    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs 5. but why ? And can the "output" be read or stored somewhere ?
I'm fairly new to C buffers and pipes, so I don't know if I'm using the right terminology.

Comment: What output did you expect? 42?

Comment: I don't understand why I get any output at all.

Comment: You don't understand that python's"print" statement creates output?

Comment: I didn't know the output would be transfered to my program stdout, but now I do.

Comment: You don't understand your own code? Why did you write it? You are writing a Python statement to Python, it is executing it, and printing the result.

Answer (score 1):

When you write like this you're effectively writing to the `stdin` of the process you just started, in this case the python REPL. On Linux the python REPL is getting the expression directly ie it's not being typed in. This is ths system command

```
read(0, "print(2+3)", 4096) = 10
```

If you were doing this in the terminal each character is being read in one at a time by the terminal and when it gets carriage return it writes a newline `\n` ie

```
read(0, "\r", 1)                        = 1
write(1, "\n", 1
```

It then performs the calculation and write the result out

```
write(1, "5\n", 25
```

You're by passing the terminal and writing the data directly to the stdin of the python interpreter. If you want to see how this can easily break try this code.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    FILE *pystream = popen("python","w"); // Calling the python console
    fprintf(pystream,"print(2+3)"); // Making it do something   
    fprintf(pystream,"print(2+3)"); // Making it do something   
    pclose(pystream); // Closing the pipe
    return 0;
}
```

You will get a syntax error, to make it work the stdin needs to be fed a carriage return or a newline to separate the two lines ie add a carriage return...

```
fprintf(pystream,"print(2+3)\r");
```

Comment: And that process writes in my program's stdout I assume ?

Comment: Is there any way to change that behavior, let's say to store the output in a string instead of it being displayed in the terminal for example.

Comment: I wouldn't use popen if you're trying to do something fancy and reading and writing between processes is getting fancy, popen is quite inflexible. You can find a good write up on where it starts to become painful at the bottom of this page..  http://www.microhowto.info/howto/capture_the_output_of_a_child_process_in_c.html#idp50992

Comment: What should I use then ? Can I just create a pipe with the python REPL as stdin and something like a char array as stdout ?

Comment: You normally fork to get a child process and then use pipes for stdin/stdout/stderr etc to and from both processes. Have a look at the link in my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

The standard output of the command you're executing is connected to the standard output of your program, so when the Python writes to its standard output, it appears on the standard output of your process too.

If you had pending output before you ran Python, that won't be flushed and will appear after Python returns.  For example,

```
std::cout << "Hello";
```

(no `endl`, no `\n` in the string) before `popen()` and

```
std::cout << " World\n";
```

after `pclose()` means that you'll see the Python output before `Hello World`.

---

If you want to write to Python and read the results back in your program, you can no longer use `popen()` and `pclose()`.  Instead, you need to use `pipe()` twice (one pipe to talk to Python, one pipe to read from Python), and you need to use `fork()`, `exec()`, `dup2()` — probably; `dup()` otherwise — and `close()` to make the operations work.  You'll be using file descriptors and hence `read()` and `write()` system calls in the parent process, too.

Those are all C functions (system calls) more than C++ functions.

This code works:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    int p1[2];
    int p2[2];
    if (pipe(p1) != 0 || pipe(p2) != 0)
        return 1;
    int pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        return 1;
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(p1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(p2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(p1[0]);
        close(p1[1]);
        close(p2[0]);
        close(p2[1]);
        execlp("python", "python", (char *)0);
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to exec python\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        close(p1[0]);
        close(p2[1]);
        const char command[] = "print(2+3)\n";
        int len = strlen(command);
        if (write(p1[1], command, len) != len)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to write command to python\n");
            return 1;
        }
        close(p1[1]);
        char buffer[256];
        int nbytes;
        if ((nbytes = read(p2[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer))) <= 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to read response from python\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Python said: (%d) [%.*s]\n", nbytes, nbytes, buffer);
        close(p2[0]);
        printf("Finished\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The bad news is that changing this code to write more than one command while synchronously reading a response from Python does not work.  Python does not process each line separately as it does when its input is a terminal; it reads all the data before it responds at all.  You can work around that with `python -i`, but then the prompts from Python appear on `stderr`.  So, you can redirect that to `/dev/null` to lose it:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    int p1[2];
    int p2[2];
    if (pipe(p1) != 0 || pipe(p2) != 0)
        return 1;
    int pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        return 1;
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(p1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(p2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(p1[0]);
        close(p1[1]);
        close(p2[0]);
        close(p2[1]);
        int dn = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
        if (dn >= 0)
        {
            dup2(dn, STDERR_FILENO);
            close(dn);
        }
        execlp("python", "python", "-i", (char *)0);
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to exec python\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        close(p1[0]);
        close(p2[1]);
        const char *commands[] =
        {
            "print(2+3)\n",
            "print(3+4)\n",
        };
        enum { NUM_COMMANDS = sizeof(commands) / sizeof(commands[0]) };
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COMMANDS; i++)
        {
            int len = strlen(commands[i]);
            if (write(p1[1], commands[i], len) != len)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to write command to python\n");
                return 1;
            }
            char buffer[256];
            int nbytes;
            if ((nbytes = read(p2[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer))) <= 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to read response from python\n");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Python said: (%d) [%.*s]\n", nbytes, nbytes, buffer);
        }
        close(p1[1]);
        close(p2[0]);
        printf("Finished\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Without redirection of `stderr`:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> >>> Python said: (2) [5
]
>>> Python said: (2) [7
]
Finished
```

With redirection of `stderr`:

```
Python said: (2) [5
]
Python said: (2) [7
]
Finished
```

The disadvantage of losing the standard error output to `/dev/null` is that you won't get any notice when Python objects to what you send it to execute — the code will hang.  Working around that is fun (a third pipe, and using `poll()` or `epoll()` or — perish the thought — `select()` would be one way around the problem).